# Configuring Google PubSub Subscriber Ack time

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to understand PubSub Subscriber ack time lease management,  I look at the three properties in https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/lease-management

**Maximum acknowledgment extension period.**

1. Is this the period after the default acknowledgement period of 10s
   or the total time PubSub waits for acknowledgement?
2. If none of the subscribers ack by the end of this period the message
   would go to the dead-letter topic. Is this assumption correct?

**Maximum duration for each acknowledgment extension.**

This value should be less than Maximum acknowledgment extension period and this is the time PubSub waits before redelivering.

**Minimum duration for each acknowledgment extension.**

It is not very clear to me on how to set the value. If PubSub is waiting for **Maximum duration for each acknowledgment extension** to redeliver how does this value matter?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of time you can extend a message's acknowledgement deadline by using the modify acknowledgement deadline request is known as the maximum acknowledgement extension period. You can specify a time limit for the subscriber clients' message processing using this property. Ten seconds are the default value.

For each request to modify an acknowledgement deadline, the maximum period for each acknowledgement extension is the amount of time that can be added to the original deadline. You can set a time limit for how long a message will be resent using this property. Redelivery happens when the first subscriber processing the message fails or becomes unwell and is unable to send the request to modify the acknowledgement deadline.

The minimum period for each acknowledgement extension is the shortest period of time by which the acknowledgement deadline for each request to modify the acknowledgement deadline may be extended. The earliest possible time before a message is redelivered is defined by this property. The message will be resent if no subscribers acknowledge it by the end of the Maximum acknowledgment extension period. The message will also be resent by PubSub if none of the subscribers acknowledge it by the end of the Maximum duration for each acknowledgment extension.